# Keyframes visible in 'Layout' view but not in 'Animation' view

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm following the donut tutorial on YouTube and am struggling to add keyframes through the node editor like the author does.

Well, the keyframes appear to be added as I can see them when I switch to the 'Layout' view, but they are nowhere to be seen in 'Animation' view.

The animation also works when I hit the space bar.

I've also been sure make sure that my object is selected.

How do I view the keyframes in Animation mode?

[image]

**Timeline in Animation view**
[image]

**Timeline in Layout view**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Dope Sheet* you have *Only Show Selected* enabled (the white arrow on blue button) which only shows you channels of selected objects **and data**.

In my example it shows keyframes on a cube which are animating the location, because the cube is selected:

[image: only show selected]

But there is something missing if you look at the *Timeline*, there are two more keyframes which don't show up in the *Dope Sheet*, this is because in the *Timeline* the option *View* > *Only Keyframes from Selected Channels* is disabled:

[image: more keyframes visible]

[image: disabled selected channels]

Those two extra keyframes are animating a shader node in the material of the cube - but **the node is not selected**. This is why it doesn't show up in the *Dope Sheet* that is set to only show channels of **selected data**. And in your screenshots it seems that the *Set Position* node is not selected, therefore it will not be shown in the *Dope Sheet*.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you